# Subprocess AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, list

I found a program that outputs your wifi password to the console but I get the following error:

> `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'`

What should I do? (I use python 3.8.)

```py
import subprocess

data = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profiles']).decode('utf-8', errors="backslashreplace").split('\n')
profiles = [i.split(":")[1][1:-1] for i in data if "All User Profile" in i]
for i in profiles:
    try:
        results = subprocess.check_output(['netsh', 'wlan', 'show', 'profile', i, 'key=clear']).decode('utf-8', errors="backslashreplace").split('\n')
        results = [b.split(":")[1][1:-1] for b in results if "Key Content" in b]
        try:
            print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, results[0]))
        except IndexError:
            print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, ""))
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print ("{:<30}|  {:<}".format(i, "ENCODING ERROR"))
input("")
```

Comment: Could you also add the `traceback` to the question ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what that is.

Comment: It's the Error you got starting with `AttributeError: list object has no read ...`. Please post the exact error you got, which will help us easily track the bug